# change in system causing custom growl send script to send blank message body

Tags: php, shell, growl

I am using class.growl.php to send myself server updates on my debian machine it sends the body content fine but on centos 5.6 it sends them with an empty body when run from cron but fine when run manually
class.growl.php:

```
<?PHP
class Growl
{
    const GROWL_PRIORITY_LOW = -2;
    const GROWL_PRIORITY_MODERATE = -1;
    const GROWL_PRIORITY_NORMAL = 0;
    const GROWL_PRIORITY_HIGH = 1;
    const GROWL_PRIORITY_EMERGENCY = 2;

    private $appName;
    private $address;
    private $notifications;
    private $password;
    private $port;

    public function __construct($address, $password = '', $app_name = 'PHP Growl')
    {
        $this->appName       = utf8_encode($app_name);
        $this->address       = $address;
        $this->notifications = array();
        $this->password      = $password;
        $this->port          = 9887;
    }

    public function addNotification($name, $enabled = true)
    {
        $this->notifications[] = array('name' => utf8_encode($name), 'enabled' => $enabled);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $data         = '';
        $defaults     = '';
        $num_defaults = 0;

        for($i = 0; $i < count($this->notifications); $i++)
        {
            $data .= pack('n', strlen($this->notifications[$i]['name'])) . $this->notifications[$i]['name'];
            if($this->notifications[$i]['enabled'])
            {
                $defaults .= pack('c', $i);
                $num_defaults++;
            }
        }

        // pack(Protocol version, type, app name, number of notifications to register)
        $data  = pack('c2nc2', 1, 0, strlen($this->appName), count($this->notifications), $num_defaults) . $this->appName . $data . $defaults;
        $data .= pack('H32', md5($data . $this->password));

        return $this->send($data);
    }

    public function notify($name, $title, $message, $priority = 0, $sticky = false)
    {
        $name     = utf8_encode($name);
        $title    = utf8_encode($title);
        $message  = utf8_encode($message);
        $priority = intval($priority);

        $flags = ($priority & 7) * 2;
        if($priority < 0) $flags |= 8;
        if($sticky) $flags |= 256;

        // pack(protocol version, type, priority/sticky flags, notification name length, title length, message length. app name length)
        $data = pack('c2n5', 1, 1, $flags, strlen($name), strlen($title), strlen($message), strlen($this->appName));
        $data .= $name . $title . $message . $this->appName;
        $data .= pack('H32', md5($data . $this->password));

        return $this->send($data);
    }

    private function send($data)
    {
        if(function_exists('socket_create') && function_exists('socket_sendto'))
        {
            $sck = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
            socket_sendto($sck, $data, strlen($data), 0x100, $this->address, $this->port);
            return true;
        }
        elseif(function_exists('fsockopen'))
        {
            $fp = fsockopen('udp://' . $this->address, $this->port);
            fwrite($fp, $data);
            fclose($fp);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

check.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

SERVICE='httpd'
//Debian SERVICE='apache2'

echo $(service httpd status) > stat.txt
//Debian echo $(/etc/init.d/apache2 status) > stat.txt

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
php -q ~/growl/send.php Run 'Notification' 'httpd is Running fine' // Apache2
else
php -q ~/growl/send.php Error 'Error' 'httpd is Down' // Apache2
fi
#rm stat.txt

SERVICE='mysqld'
//Debian SERVICE='mysql'

echo $(service mysqld status) > stat.txt //Debian mysql

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
php -q ~/growl/send.php Run 'Notification' 'Mysqld is Running fine' //mysql
else
php -q ~/growl/send.php Error 'Error' 'Mysqld is Down'  //mysql
fi
#rm stat.txt
```

Send.php:

```
<?php
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/class.growl.php';
// check for all required arguments
// first argument is always name of script!
if ($argv[1] == 'ls'){
 echo "Test\n";
 echo "Error\n";
 echo "Run\n";
 exit (0);
}
if ($argc != 4) {
die("Usage: send.php <Notification To Send 'ls to list'> <Title> <Message>\n");
}

// remove first argument
array_shift($argv);

$ApacheFile = 'stat.txt';
$Notification = $argv[0];
$Title = $argv[1];
$Message = $argv[2];

if (file_exists($ApacheFile)){
$fh = fopen($ApacheFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($ApacheFile));
fclose($fh);
$Message = $theData;
}

$growl = new Growl('192.168.1.99', 'scorpio', 'Notify');
$growl->addNotification('Test');
$growl->addNotification('Error');
$growl->addNotification('Run');
$growl->register();
if ($Notification == 'Test'){
$growl->notify($Notification, $Title, $Message); 
}else if ($Notification == 'Error'){
$growl->notify($Notification, $Title, $Message); 
}else if($Notification == 'Run'){
$growl->notify($Notification, $Title, $Message); 
}
```

cron: */5 * * * * /root/growl/check.sh